# Why does my Ford Focus 2018 not go past 55mph?

Tags: transmission, fuel-system, pump

My Ford Focus 2018 recently has been giving me issues. It stalled on me and wouldn’t turn back on and then gave me an engine code P0087 - Fuel Rail/System Pressure - Too Low - I just got a call back from the mechanic I took it too. He got it to run again after changing the high pressure fuel sensor. But he said he couldn’t get it past 55mph, and suggests it could be the transmission. I just want to ask this community if it could be anything else potentially? A bad fuel pump, or something?

Comment: Does this car have the  DPS 6 dual clutch transmission?

Comment: Forgot to ask: Can you scan car for transmission DTC codes?

Answer (score 1):

Your mechanic could be correct. The ford focus had numerous issues over the years with the DPS6 dual clutch transmission. What I would do is have it scanned for codes and see if any transmission codes are in the module. I am not saying this your problem, but I diagnosed this problem for a friend with his 2015 Ford Focus transmission module.He dealt with the ford dealership with his issues.As for your question, it could be something else, but definitely scan the car for trouble codes with the transmission first. DTC codes from transmission were: PO702:00-28 PO805:00-AF PO809:00-28 P2872:00-E and PO809. This was a friends 2015 Ford Focus.

Comment: I've seen similar symptoms on a very different Ford. The transmission speed sensor was faulty. The van thought it was found 110 MPH or something and it was cutting out at 55 MPH. The governor kicked in. This would also show up on a transmission scan.

Comment: Ford Focus had many issues with this particular transmission. google ford focus lawsuit.

Comment: lawsuit was for Canada, not sure of other countries. Thank You @Jupiter for comment.